# Phonegap with jquery mobile "hello world" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

just trying to get jquery mobile firing with phonegap, but I can't get my hello world firing.

All of the references to the Js is correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery_mobile.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


    function onDeviceReady() {
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $(document).bind("deviceready", function(){
             navigator.notification.alert("hello world");
         });
      });
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
     <title>Hello With JQuery Mobile</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.1.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var onDeviceReady = function() {
            alert("OnDeviceReady fired.");
        };

        function init() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
        }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body onload="init();">

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great! The document is not ready for adding the event listener to until the body loads.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't working. I need something that will only fire once jQuery, jquery mobile and document body has loaded. I tested what happens if I removed jQuery mobile script tag, and this still functions. I also checked `typeof(jQuery)` which didn't fire, showing that it isn't dependent on those scripts, and it isn't waiting for them.

Comment: I'm confused about your question. You can remove jQuery Mobile because its not being used in the hello world example, but everything in the head section should be loaded before the body's onload.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the reference where the html and js ar located in Xcode?

You should try to start debugging by placing something in the body of the html and see if that appears when you compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the addEventListener and Function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).bind('deviceready', function(){
            navigator.notification.alert("hello world");
        });
    });
</script>
```

There is no need to listen for 'deviceready' twice. The document will be ready first, followed by JQM firing deviceready.

I hope it helps!

Comment: @MildFuzz Have you tried placing other functions inside the call to see if they fire?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  Commenting out jquery or jquerymobile reference caused the app to work but i could not get it to work with both in the header.  Both files were in the www folder of phonegap.  I even tried referencing the code from the jquery.com but it didn't work.